# Challenging Edits

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, suggested-edits

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071706/specialization-with-constraints) that was recently edited by another user. Specifically, he added the [specialization](/questions/tagged/specialization) tag (presumably because the word is in the question title), which I object to. When I wrote the question, I noticed that that particular tag does not refer to Haskell specialization; instead it is about C++ templates. Presumably, users subscribed to that tag may not even know Haskell, and certainly my question has nothing to do with C++.

What's the correct course of action?

1. Re-edit the question to remove the tag
2. Edit the tag to include Haskell (`specialization` is certainly a reasonable tag in reference to Haskell, albeit a bit meta-feature)
3. Something else?

Comment: 4. all of the above :)

Comment: I'm concerned about editing the tag because although I know about specialization in Haskell, it might be relevant to other languages as well. It'd be nice to just fix the tag for good...

Comment: Eric, It will be reviewed by other users, so even if you made a mistake someone else will spot it :)

Comment: Are you referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071706/specialization-with-constraints)? Saurabh appeared to have [added the constraints tag](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21071706/revisions), not the specialization tag.

Comment: How...odd. In that case, I suppose I need to self-censor.

Comment: @Eric I guess you just took one of the suggested tags and didn't realise what it was until later? No harm done in any case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag [specialization](/questions/tagged/specialization) is, as wiki states, meant for C++ so using it for your question was absolutely invalid edit.

Using it as [meta-tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) is also strongly discouraged on C++.

Because that tag is only a subset of [templates](/questions/tagged/templates), and it's name is misleading, I'd suggest tag renaming (to include C++ or template or both in its name) or even burnination.

Comment: As you can see, I edited the wiki to include GHC/Haskell, which was accepted, but I was not familiar with the concept of meta-tags until this answer. Now I'm on board and might also support burnination (also in agreement with you about [tag:constraint]).